# Is it standard practice to always have internal A records for an AD Domain point to GCs?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, active-directory

Full disclosure: I'm not an AD guy so this might pertain to something obvious.  I apologize in advance if that's the case - I did try searching for prior questions regarding this.

I'm installing a Linux-based web application server in an AD environment (vanilla CentOS 5.x - no special integration with AD).  The app performs LDAPS queries against Global Catalog servers.  In order to discover which AD server to talk to, it performs a DNS Lookup for A records pertaining to the AD domain (foo.int).  This specific query appears to be failing (I'm still looking into it).

In the meantime though, I'd like to confirm a few things:

- If I'm pointing the Linux server to Microsoft DNS servers, and query for the AD domain (foot.in), is it reasonable to assume that I should get A records pointing to some GCs?
- Is the availability of A records for GCs something that is pretty standard?  Or is this something that varies from environment to environment? In other words, are there some environments that just don't have internal A records published at all for DCs?
- Are these specific records something that is automatically managed/updated, or are they manually added/edited by admins?

Comment: You can't know which DC is a GC by querying for the DC A records. You need to query for the GC SRV records.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If I'm pointing the Linux server to Microsoft DNS servers, and query for the AD domain (foot.in), is it reasonable to assume that I should get A records pointing to some GCs?

No, what you will get is all *Domain Controllers*  in the domain not necessarily just the Global Catalog Servers. If you just want the Global Catalog servers you can query `_gc._tcp.<your_AD_FQDN>` or you can query `_gc.<your_site_name>._sites.<your_AD_FQDN>` if you just want the GCs in a specific site. This is actually an SRV type record.

> Is the availability of A records for GCs something that is pretty standard? Or is this something that varies from environment to environment? In other words, are there some environments that just don't have internal A records published at all for DCs?

All DCs will have an A record, It should be auto registered. But it's possibly that if auto-dns registration is turned off for the NIC that there will be no A record if someone didn't do it manually. AD will be broken if this stuff is turned off.

> Are these specific records something that is automatically managed/updated, or are they manually added/edited by admins?

The `_sites`, `_msdcs`, `_tcp`, and `_udp` zones are managed automagically. The A records should be too, as long as someone hasn't done something silly with the config to turn this stuff off.